# How do I remove the "close" link from my modal dialog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, hyperlink, modal-dialog

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have installed the query-modal gem (https://github.com/dei79/jquery-modal-rails) to help me generate modal dialogs.  So I include this

```
<%= link_to_modal "Add Item”, "#add_form", :class=>'modal_button' %>
```

and my modal appears.  The problem is, it is rendered with this “Close” link at the bottom and I don’t want that to be there.  Does anyone know how I get rid of it?  The HTML that is generated is

```
<a href="#close-modal" rel="modal:close" class="close-modal">Close</a>
```

**Edit:** Here's the code for the add_form, as requested by the comment.

```
<div id="add_form">
<%= form_for @my_object, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %> <span class="required">*</span><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :day %> <span class="required">*</span><br>
    <%= f.text_field :day, class: 'datepicker' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <input type="hidden" id="_method" name="_method" value="" />
    <%= button_to "Save", { :action => "create" }, :method => :post, :class => 'button' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the HTML of 'add_form'

Comment: It is included as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since you don't want that close button, there is a way that I did it with only css

First of all you should have your `require_tree .` to be below `require jquery.modal` in your `application.css` file, like this

```
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require jquery.modal
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

Then create a `base.css` file in your stylesheet folder

```
stylesheets
  |application.css
  |base.css
```

and in `base.css` file add this

```
.modal a.close-modal {
  display: none;
}
```

This was the final result for me
http://postimg.org/image/dh2wp08jf/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to disable the functionality which allows the modal to be closed when clicked outside. If that's correct you need to change it like

```
<div id="modal" class="modal hide fade in" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
```

**Hiding close button** can be easily done as that's coming from HTML and CSS

```
.close {display: none;}
```

or

```
.modal a.close-modal {
  display: none;
}
```